# Resharper color identifiers bolding variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have turned on Resharper color identifiers to use it for TT syntax highlighting, however I don't understand some of the things it highlights in my code now.

For example, what does it mean when a variable is bold:

[image]

I can see it suggesting ternary operator and when I add it, it's no longer bold, but I suppose there's more to that, as otherwise it seems redundant.

[image]

Is there any documentation on what do the color indentifiers identify? I only see scarce info on their site [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Coding_Assistance__Syntax_Highlighting.html)

Comment: bold apparently means mutable variables. Those you assign more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first sample, it highlights it bold, because it is re-set later. So, although `parentId` is initialized with `Browser.GetCurrentParentId()`, it is overwritten by `GetParentIdFromNavPickOrUrl()`.

In the second sample however, the expression `Browser.GetCurrentParentId() ?? GetParentIdFromNavPickOrUrl()` is first evaluated, and only *then* assigned to the variable.

Comment: OK, I see only little sense in this, though, as the overwrite is conditional... Does order of assign<>evaluate really matter in case of local fields? I would see a reason if that was a non-automatic property, but in this case... Oh well:)

Comment: Not from a technical point of view. However, multiple assignment of local parameters/variables might be considered bad practice. So ReSharper at least visualises that; no warnings or suggestion though.